# Diferença entre WinExec e ShellExecute

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Bom dia, pessoal!

Estou com uma dúvida pessoal que ainda não encontrei resposta, por isso venho até aqui.

Qual a diferença entre `WinExec` e `ShellExecute` no Delphi?

Faço esse questionamento pois recentemente tive um problema ao tentar utilizar o `WinExec` (tentava instalar um serviço do Windows, mas sem sucesso), mas ao utilizar o `ShellExecute`, o serviço foi instalado normalmente.

O que um tem que o outro não tem? Utilizei o Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `ShellExecute` funciona como o menu Executar do Windows, e este é o seu melhor benefício de uso, o `WinExec` já esta em desuso com o sucessor `CreateProcess`.

`WinExec` executa uma instrução simples a partir de outra aplicação, um execmplo seria abrir a caculadora do Windows clicando em algum botão de dentro de sua aplicação!

Já o `ShellExecute` é bem mais complexo, ele opera sobe um "arquivo", um exemplo seria você pedir para imprimir um determinado arquivo a partir de sua aplicação! Acredito que você conseguiria instalar o serviço com a linha de comando correta!

Documentação [WinExec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx)

Alguns detalhes no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127504/which-are-the-differences-between-winexec-and-shellexecute)

Mais detalhes relevantes [aqui.](https://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-shellexecute-para-executar-aplicativos-externos/613)

Edit:

Dentro do Help da IDE você pode navegar o item `Microsoft Windows Plataform SDK` e obtera mais detalhes sobre o [ShellExecute](http://ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe4/ShellCC/platform/shell/reference/functions/shellexecute.htm), este não é um link para navegação, serve apenas dentro do Help

Comment: Brilhante! Obrigado pela explicação Júnior Moreira!