# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de criar um serviço do Windows?

Tags: delphi, windows, services

Quero saber quais as vantagens e desvantagens de criar um *serviço do Windows* e se:

- Se é de fácil manutenção;
- Se alguém já teve problemas com isso;
- Se exige algum conhecimento específico, fora a linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vantagens:

- Ele é controlado pelo sistema operacional e pode iniciar automaticamente  no *boot* ou sob demanda ou reiniciando quando há alguma falha e pode ser feito remotamente de forma direta
- Não precisa ter um usuário *logado* para executá-lo e pode se passar por outros usuários
- Tem mais controle sobre a segurança e controle de acesso
- Não fica visível
- Não pode ser fechado por meios normais, mas pode ser controlado de forma até melhor que uma aplicação normal, inclusive facilmente parando um processo pendurado, e pode controlar e monitorar tudo isto

Desvantagens:

- Não pode rodar mais de uma instância
- Geralmente precisa de privilégio de administrador e precisa de uma instalação dele, e claro, uma atualização não é tão simples quanto sobrepor um executável
- É mais complicado desenvolver e depurar, se não souber fazer certo e entender o que tem que ser diferente pode ser problemático (não costuma ser uma boa ideia para quem não domina muito bem desenvolvimento de software a não ser que faça algo muito trivial)
- Não interage com o usuário

Precisa conhecer toda API dos serviços e as peculiaridades que ela exige.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando o que o Maniero disse:

**Nível de manutenção:** A manutenção de um serviço (ao meu ponto de vista) é tão simples quanto uma aplicação VCL. Visto que normalmente o serviço roda apenas em uma máquina, problemas de atualização são raros. Ter um planejamento legal para atualização (não realizar alterações em horário onde o serviço é mais utilizado) é um ótimo início. O código utilizado numa aplicação visual, é o mesmo utilizado num serviço. Então, não há muitos problemas quanto a isso. 
Para `debug` eu particularmente acho chato. Nos meus casos, eu tive que criar diretivas de compilação para essas situações, nada muito complexo, apenas "chato".

**Problemas enfrentados:**

1: Problemas ao tentar instalar serviço através do comando `WinExec` (consegui resolver usando o `ShellExecute`) [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255859/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-winexec-e-shellexecute/255917#255917) tem uma explicação da solução;

2: Windows não iniciava o serviço corretamente (foi necessário uma formatação da estação, mas houve muita dor de cabeça até descobrir que era isso);

3: Cuidado com usuário que tenham "dedos nervosos", tente encapsular o seu serviço, no que diz respeito deixar o mais longe possível do usuário.

**Conhecimentos Específicos:** É muito relativo dizer que precisa ou que não precisa de conhecimento em outra linguagem, isso vai muito da sua necessidade. Se você for desenvolver um serviço que reenvia NFC-e em contingência, você precisa ter conhecimento em XML e Web Services; Para um serviço que gera arquivos texto para importação de outro sistema, apenas conhecimento básico. Ao menu ponto de vista, não há um padrão ou lógica que defina se há ou não necessidade.

Comment: Queria saber mais sobre isso para ver se era vantagem ou não criar um... Obrigado pela Explicação.

Comment: Vou Verificar o link e me aprofundar mais... Obrigado.